# How to get a value from the last inserted row using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any codeigniter function to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this code:

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Refer:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: This is used to get last inserted id, but i want to get the row.

Comment: with help of this id you can retrieve last inserted row.

Comment: If you just inserted the row, you already have the details - why do you need to get it back from the database? @Mani already shown how to get the insert id.

Comment: how about idless table?

Comment: I wonder if the last inserted row is synonymous with the last insert you made? What if the website is being used by thousands of people all over the world, and an insert was made just after the insert you just performed?

Answer (score 9):

There is no special function for that. But you can get the id of row that you've just inserted and then get it's data:

```
$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);

$id = $this->db->insert_id();
$q = $this->db->get_where('table_name', array('id' => $id));
return $q->row();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Active Record  method after insertion. return last inserted id

```
function insert($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('tablename', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html) is reference

Answer (score 2):

I have tips for you. When you want to insert data, please return your data array and you can edit it.

```
  public function set_alb_photos() {
     $data = array(
      'alp_title' => $this->input->post('alp_title'),
      'alp_file_location' => $this->input->post('alp_file_location'),
      'alp_album_id' => $this->input->get('alb_id'),
      'alp_created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
      'alp_updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
     );
     $this->db->insert('alb_photos', $data);
     return $data;
   }
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to get last inserted row from the table.

```
$last = $this->db->order_by('id',"desc")->limit(1)->get('tablename')->row();
    print_r($last);
```

Comment: Provide some description.

Comment: In case different people are using the same database, you are likely to get a wrong id. I would advise the use of $id = $this->db->insert_id();

Answer (score 1):

Try this only with active record of codeigniter. This code gives you the last row of your table.

```
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$query = $this->db->get('tablename');
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get inserted data by below code,

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table1', array('id' => $id)); //get inserted data
return $query->result_array();
```

Refer:https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
$this->db->get('mytable', 1,0)
```

Comment: this will be used for applying limit. See [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 0):

Try this depending on the options and return  :

```
$data = {} //your array;
// now if your $data array contained all the values of the new row just do this
function yourFunction(){
  // insert into array into db
  $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
  // get created rows id
  $id = $this->db->insert_id();
  // update your $data array with the new generated id and return it
  $data['id'] = $id;
  return $data;
}


// Option 2: if row has fields that auto populates (example current timestamp)
function yourFunctionAlt(){
  // insert into array into db
  $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
  // get created rows id
  $id = $this->db->insert_id();
  // get row as a array 
  $_rowArray = $this-db->get_where('table_name',array('id'=>$id)->row_array();
  return $_rowArray;
  // or get as a object
  $_Object = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('id'=>$id);
  return $_Object;
}
```