# Codeigniter function to retrieve last inserted mysql value

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

To begin with, I'm aware to the:

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

With that I will get the id of the last inserted mysql value, but I didn't manage to find any info about the way to retrieve the last inserted value to another colomn,  let's say we have a field with name *weight*, I will get the *id* with **insert_id()** but how to get the *weight* value without the need to write a SQL statement?

I was reading the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html?highlight=insert_id) and only thing I can maybe use is the **last_query()** method, but I'm not that sure if that will work, is there anything similar?

Comment: this is one of the million reasons people use data access objects (DAO) these days.. CI is very basic...

Comment: `last_query()` will only return the last query string, not it's result (e.g. SELECT * FROM sometable....). Maybe someone else can think of a way, but my guess you'll just have make another query of the db.

Comment: @Pacio yes, that is what I'm thinking, but was the only thing kinda related that I found, Gogol I'm aware of that, but I was thinking since they have insert_id() method, it should be something similar to get another value.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433251/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-last-inserted-row-using-codeigniter

Comment: @Diksha that is from 2013, on that year we didn't had codeigniter 3, and also I can't see any valid answer there, except some SQL query's!

Comment: @Bogdan, I believe question is not about codeigniter 3.

Comment: @DevOps I put a post tag with codeigniter-3.

Comment: @Bogdan Yes dear , but your question is about concept.

Comment: @Bogdan theoretically speaking, it is not possible AFAIK. you have insert_id() because there is only one primary key column. How will the db class understand which value you want (supposing you are looking for insert_value() )? If you say.. return all the columns.. then.. the insert query will have a big overhead and the write operations will take much more time. A normal insert won't need that overhead. DAO is the only way you can get through this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get last record by using

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
$query = $this->db->get_where('your_table_name', array('your_id_field' => $id));
return $query->row();
```

Comment: that is not the answer to this question. It basically means that the system needs to query the db again.

Comment: This is the only way by which you can get what you want

Comment: yup agreed @dhruv

Comment: Ok, I will accept this answer since there isn't another way around! Thank you!